# Run Electron/NW.js App in Chrome Tab

Tags: google-chrome-app, electron, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a Chrome App. Google has deprecated and will remove Chrome Apps on non-Chrome OS platforms in 2018.

They recommend using either NW.js (with native Chrome API support) or Electron (with polyfill Chrome API support). I need to continue supporting Chrome Apps for Chrome OS. Both of these seem to currently or probably will cover my use case, persistent filesystem access.

However, I currently have an option to run in a Chrome tab, using the `open(url)` native web function. Can this behavior be replicated using NW.js or Electron?

Comment: Postman is an electron application that runs on chrome, i think you can use them as example

Comment: I'm asking how to run it inside a browser tab, I know it should be possible to port and run in a native window.